# Why is the post-composing map of f dual to the pre-composing map of f?

Tags: category-theory

I was reading in Riehl's book "Category Theory in Context (2016)" and I couldnot understand the proof of Lemma 1.2.3 on page 11

Let $C$ be a category, $f:x \rightarrow y$ is a morphism in $C$, and $c \in C$ is an object in $C$. We can define the post-composition map of $f$:
$$f_{\ast} : C(c,x) \rightarrow C(c,y) : \alpha \mapsto f \circ \alpha$$
and the pre-composition map of $f$ :
$$f^{\ast} : C(y,c) \rightarrow C(x,c) : \alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ f$$
We can also define the post-composition map of the dual $f^{op} : y \rightarrow x$ in $C^{op}$ :
$$(f^{op})_{\ast} : C^{op}(c,y) \rightarrow C^{op}(c,x) : \alpha^{op} \mapsto f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op} = (\alpha \circ f)^{op}$$

Now, Riehl claims that $(f^{op})_{\ast} = f^{\ast}$, because $C^{op}(c,x) = C(x,c)$ and $C^{op}(c,y) = C(y,c)$, and "post-composition with $f^{op}$ translates to pre-composition with $f$ in the opposite category $C$." I do not understand this. Can anyone clarify this to me and explain why $(f^{op})_{\ast} = f^{\ast}$ ?

I have a second question related to this. We also have the dual of the post-composing map $f_{\ast}$:
$$(f_{\ast})^{op} : C^{op}(c,y) \rightarrow C^{op}(c,x) : \alpha^{op} \mapsto ???$$
What is $(f_{\ast})^{op}(\alpha^{op})$ and can we conclude that $(f_{\ast})^{op} = (f^{op})_{\ast}$ ?

I hope anyone can help me with these questions and can give me a detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$-^{op} : C \to C^{op}$ can be applied on objects and maps. It is the identity on objects and flips the direction of maps. It also reverses composition $(f \circ g)^{op} = g^{op} \circ f^{op}$

The proof first shows that (i) $f : x \to y \in C$ is an isomorphism and (ii) for all $c \in C$, $f_* : C(c,x) \to C(c,y)$ is a bijection are equivalent.

We can apply this fact with the category $C^{op}$ and the map $f^{op} : y \to x \in C^{op}$ to get that:

- (a) $f^{op} : y \to x \in C^{op}$ is an isomorphism.
- (b) for all $c \in C^{op}$, ${f^{op}}_* : C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x)$ is a bijection.

are equivalent.

What we can now do is expand out the opposites to understand what these two statements say in terms of the non-opposite category $C$.

(a) is equivalent to $f : x \to y \in C$.

To see what (b) is equivalent to, let's expand out ${f^{op}}_*$.

Given $\alpha^{op} : c \to y \in C^{op}$

- ${f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}) : c \to x \in C^{op}$
- ${f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}) = f^{op} \circ \alpha$

This is the same as taking $\alpha : y \to c \in C$ and we can apply the opposite to the whole term:

- $({f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}))^{op} : x \to c \in C$
- $({f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}))^{op} = (f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op})^{op} = {\alpha^{op}}^{op} \circ {f^{op}}^{op} = \alpha \circ f = f^*(\alpha)$

Which is pre-composition.

So we have seen that ${f^{op}}_* : C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x)$ being a bijection is exactly the same as ${f}^* : C(y,c) \to C(x,c)$ being a bijection.

So applying the fact that (i) <=> (ii) with a carefully chosen map from the opposite category ended up proving exactly the fact that (i) <=> (iii) in the non-opposite category.

Comment: I really do not understand. I do understand your reasoning until $((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op} = (f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op})^{op}= \alpha \circ f$. Why is $((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op}$ a pre-composition? It is not even a map but a morphism in $C$. And how does this translate this into "that $(f^{op})_{\ast} : C^{op}(c,y) \rightarrow C^{op}(c,x)$ being a bijection is exactly the same as $f^{\ast} : C(y,c) \rightarrow C(x,c)$ being a bijection?"

Comment: This line $$({f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}))^{op} = (f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op})^{op} = {\alpha^{op}}^{op} \circ {f^{op}}^{op} = \alpha \circ f$$ shows that $({f^{op}}_*(\alpha^{op}))^{op} = f^*(\alpha)$.

Comment: The type of ${f^{op}}_*$ is $$C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x).$$ This is the same as $$C(y,c) \to C(x,c)$$ so we can equally well use ${f^{op}}_*$ on $C^{op}$ maps as we can on $C$ maps. The types just flip around.

Comment: I learned that a pre-composition is a map, so $f^{\ast}$ is a pre-composition, but $((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op}$ is not a map, but a morphism in $C$. I can see that $C^{op}(c,x) = C(x,c)$ and $C^{op}(c,y) = C(y,c)$. But what are types? Why can we use $(f^{op})_{\ast}$ in the same way on $C^{op}$ maps as on $C$ maps? How does $(f^{op})_{\ast}$ act on a $C$ map?

Comment: Yes,

$$((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op} : C^{op}(c,x)$$

but consider the function that takes $\alpha^{op}$ and gives $((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op}$

$$\alpha^{op} \mapsto ((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op} : C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x).$$

Comment: We can use $(f^{op})_{\ast}$ on maps like $\alpha^{op} : C^{op}(c,y)$ because $(f^{op})_{\ast}$ has type $C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x).$

But we saw that $C^{op}(c,y) \to C^{op}(c,x) = C(y,c) \to C(x,c)$ so  you can also use it on maps like $\alpha : C(c,y)$.

Comment: I really have no idea what you are saying, I am very confused. Let's recapitulate. (a) We have a map $(f^{op})_{\ast}:C^{op}(c,y) \rightarrow C^{op}(c,x):\alpha^{op} \mapsto f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op} = (\alpha \circ f)^{op}$. From this we have established $((f^{op})_{\ast} (\alpha^{op}))^{op} = (f^{op} \circ \alpha^{op})^{op}= \alpha \circ f = f^{\ast}(\alpha)$. (b) We also have a map $f^{\ast}:C(y,c) \rightarrow C(x,c):\alpha \mapsto \alpha \circ f$. Finally, (c) we have $C^{op}(c,x) = C(x,c)$ and $C^{op}(c,y) = C(y,c)$. How do we go on from here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually make use of this in your argument (I've not read the whole thing), but I should point out that $-^{op}$, as an operation from $C$ to its opposite category, is not usually a functor.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, thank you very much for the correction. Fixed my post.